# Easymock and Shiro

Tags: easymock, shiro

I am trying to use AbstractShiroTest abstract class for my unit tests as explained in http://shiro.apache.org/testing.html
I have my test class:

```
public class BeanTest extends AbstractShiroTest {
...
@Test
public void testShiro() {
    Subject subjectUnderTest = createNiceMock(Subject.class);
    expect(subjectUnderTest.isAuthenticated()).andReturn(true);
    expect(subjectUnderTest.getPrincipal()).andReturn("cenap");
    setSubject(subjectUnderTest);
    assertTrue("Subject is not authenticated", SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated());
    assertNotNull("Subject principle null", SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal());
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownClass() {  
    tearDownShiro();
}
```

Both assertions fail... SecurityUtils.getSubject() returns some object but isAuthenticated() method of that object returns false and getPrincipal() method returns null. "expect" clauses do not seem to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question as it might help someone. It was a stupid mistake... 
The trick is: Do not forget adding

> **anyTimes();**

after your expect statement and so not forget calling

> **replay (subjectUnderTest);**

after that!

So your BeforeClass method should be like:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpShiro() {
    Subject subjectUnderTest = createNiceMock(Subject.class);
    expect(subjectUnderTest.isAuthenticated()).andReturn(true).anyTimes();
    expect(subjectUnderTest.getPrincipal()).andReturn(Admin).anyTimes();
    setSubject(subjectUnderTest);        
    replay (subjectUnderTest);        
}
```